# How does Gitlab CI Runner connect with Kubernetes cluster without being in Approved IP range

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, azure-aks, gitlab-ci-runner

I have an AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) cluster where I have "Approved IP addresses" enabled in the "Networking" section to only allow certain machines to connect to it via Kubectl API

[image]

I also have a Gitlab Project where I have setup Kubernetes integration via Gitalb GUI, resulting in a `gitlab-agent` installation on my AKS cluster.

[image]

I also have a Gitlab runner which is setup as a Linux VM in a Vnet/subnet different from the Vnet/subnet where my K8s cluster live.

[image]

The list of "Approved IP addresses" does NOT have the IP address of my Gitlab runner but my Gitlab runner is able to connet to my Kubernetes cluster anyways and I'm unable to run `kubectl` commands which I don't expect.

[image]

I cannot understand how is the Gitlab runner in one Vnet/subnet is able to connect with my Kubernetes cluster in another Vnet/subnet.

Comment: The Gitlab runner is able to connect to the Kubernetes cluster because it is installed as a Kubernetes executor. This means that it runs as a pod inside the cluster and communicates with the API server via the Kubernetes service account token. Since the runner is running inside the cluster, it does not need to be in the approved IP address range to connect to the API server.

Comment: The Kubernetes integration in GitLab typically works through the GitLab Agent for Kubernetes, which is deployed within your Kubernetes cluster. Once the agent is installed in your cluster, it establishes a bidirectional communication channel with GitLab.

The "Approved IP addresses" restriction in AKS networking specifically targets external attempts to access the Kubernetes API server. Since your GitLab runner operates within the cluster, it bypasses the IP restriction. Reference:
[Gitlab kubernetes executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the GitLab agent in your cluster, your cluster only needs to be able to reach GitLab, not the other way around. Your cluster establishes a connection with GitLab and receives API commands through that established connection.

Part of the [agent architecture](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/gitlab-agent/-/blob/master/doc/architecture.md?ref_type=heads) design is to enable connectivity with clusters behind a NAT or firewall. As documented in [Connecting a Kubernetes cluster with GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/):

> The agent runs in the cluster, and you can use it to:
>
> - Communicate with a cluster, which is behind a firewall or NAT.
>   [...]

In GitLab CI/CD jobs, you typically would [use the agent context](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/ci_cd_workflow.html#update-your-gitlab-ciyml-file-to-run-kubectl-commands) to communicate with the agent. This is enabled, in part, by the `$KUBECONFIG` variable which GitLab provides when connected agents are configured:

> All CI/CD jobs now include a kubeconfig file with contexts for every shared agent connection. The kubeconfig path is available in the environment variable `$KUBECONFIG`. Choose the context to run kubectl commands from your CI/CD scripts.

So, in short, your GitLab CI jobs are utilizing the connection established by the agent running in your cluster, which as stated earlier, works even if your cluster is behind a NAT or firewall that doesn't allow new inbound connections.